# How to compare 1 number to an entire array?

Tags: ruby

**Create a function that takes an array of hurdle heights and a jumper's jump height, and determine whether or not the hurdler can clear all the hurdles. A hurdler can clear a hurdle if their jump height is greater than or equal to the hurdle height.**

My code:

```
def hj (arr, h)

  i = 0


  while i < arr.length

    j = 0


    while j < arr.length  

      if arr[i] > h
      return false
      end  
      j += 1

    end


    return true

    i += 1

  end

end

puts hj([2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 8], 7)
```

- Desired output: true if h is >= to any number in the array; false if h is < any number in the array (I want true or false to display once)
- Where I'm questioning my own code:

  1. Not sure if I need two while statements
  2. the current array being passed should output false
  3. loop seems to only be comparing the first set of numbers, so 7 and 2. Not sure why the loop is stopping.
  4. Not sure if I'm utilizing true and false correctly
  5. Feel like I should be using a block for this, but not sure where to implement it.

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some solutions:

**Using loop**

```
def hj(arr, h)
  for elem in arr
    return false if elem > h
  end
  true
end
```

See? Only one loop. Actually this is the most unruby implementation.

**Using Enumerable#all?**

```
def hj(arr, h)
  arr.all?{|elem| elem <= h}
end
```

This is the most intuitive and most Ruby implementation.

**Using Enumerable#max**

If one can jump over the highest hurdle, he can jump over all hurdles.

```
def hj(arr, h)
  arr.max <= h
end
```

Comment: Kicking myself because the answer seems so easy when others point it out.  I'm over complicating it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Not sure if I need two while statements

You don't.  You only need to traverse the list once. You're traversing, not sorting / reordering.

> 3. loop seems to only be comparing the first set of numbers, so 7 and 2. Not sure why the loop is stopping.

This is because you are using `return true` as the second last statement of your outer loop.  Return interrupts function execution and returns immediately to the calling function - in this case, the last line of your program.

> 5. Feel like I should be using a block for this, but not sure where to implement it.

A block is the idiomatic ruby way to solve this.  You are, essentially, wanting to check that your second parameter is larger than any value in the list which is your first parameter.

A solution in idiomatic ruby would be

```
def hj (arr, h)
    # return true if h >= all elements in arr, false otherwise

    # given arr = [1, 2, 3] and h = 2, 
    # returns [ true, true, false ] which all? then returns as false 
    # (since all? returns the boolean AND of the results of the block evaluation

    arr.all? { |elem| elem <= h }  
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering these parts.  Very informative for a beginner like myself. Thank you.